# How to Calculating Scientific Method Using PHP

Tags: php

I'm New in PHP I just ask simply question.I have calculating number without any formula. this is working fine.Now I have using formula in calculation.Check my example..

```
<?php
$calculation = (350/ (1+(18/100))  ;
?>
```

i have getting error this
how to calculate this method

Comment: You have 3 open ( and only 2 close ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a bracket at the end

```
<?php
    $calculation = (350/ (1+(18/100)))  ;
?>
```

Comment: This is a typo/basic error which the question (should) be flagged as, answers just clog up the system.